# Latex symbol for personal website url

Tags: symbols

I have a `fancyhdr` footer with my personal data and I would like to add some cute symbol inline with my website url. I've already included the `marvosym` package and used:

- `\Letter` symbol before my email address
- `\Telefon` symbol before my phone number.

I need a nice symbol for my website url. Could you please suggest me one?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

How about

- `\Mundus` for a “World” symbol, or maybe
- `\ComputerMouse` ?

Both also from `marvosym`.

In any case have a look at the [comprehensive symbol list](http://tug.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) for further ideas.

Comment: choosed \ding{43} from pifont. Thanks for symbol list reference.

Comment: For those curious (like me!) `\ding{43}` is a hand pointing to the right.

Answer (score 6):

In 2013 the [fontawesome-package](https://ctan.org/ctan-ann/pkg/fontawesome) was published.
The package contains also some specific icons for facebook, twitter, xing, amazon... The [the comprehensive symbol list](http://tug.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) contains a section *fontawesome Web-Related Icons*.

With `\faGlobe` you get [image: Icon \faGlobe]

(The `\ding{43}` from pifont could be replaced by `\faHandORight`)

I combine this icons with `\faHome` [image: Icon \fahome] and `\faIndustry` [image] to make a difference between private and business websites.